# while using substring to print a character pattern why has i been initialized to 1 instead of 0?

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, substring

I understand this program the only doubt is in the part where *i* has been initialized to 1. As strings are stored like arrays the place at 0 should have the first character of the string right ? then why is it one. i would appreciate if you could also help me with understanding how substring method works :)).

**sample input: SCHOOL
sample output:
S
SC
SCH
SCHO
SCHOO
SCHOOL**

> ```
>  /*taking SCHOOL as example and print S SC SCH ...*/
> import java.util.*;
> public class substring
> {
>     public static void main(String args[])
>     {
>         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>         System.out.println("enter a string");
>         String word = sc.next();
>         
>         int x= word.length();
>         
>         for( int i = 1; i<=x; i++)
>         System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
>     }
>     
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `String.substring (int begIndex, int endIndex)` method, `endIndex` doesn't index the last character of the substring. It indexes the character *after* the last character of the substring.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

> Thus, the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex

Comment: so it starts from 1 instead of zero^th position am i right?

Comment: What you wrote in your question is correct:  Characters within Strings are indexed the same as elements within arrays. The first character is the "zero^th". But, in your code, the variable i is used as the ending index of a substring. The ending index of a substring points to the character after the end of the substring. 

See the example in the Oracle Java SE page I referenced.

Comment: It clicked this time ! thanks, james :) have a great day